# Automatic Unit Testing with NANT and VS2008 during build process

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, nant

I'm using VS2008 Pro and as such my c# project includes a bunch of Unit Tests written in the MS bundled unit test framework (sorry I have no idea what its official name is!). I would like to be able to run these unit tests as part of my build process.

Is it possible to get Nant to automatically run these Unit tests during a build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that worked for me is the following:

```
<exec program ="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" >
    <arg value="/testcontainer:${Test_dll}"/>
    <arg value="/resultsfile:C:\Test\TestResults.trx"/>
</exec>
```

This is just the basic nant element, although it is as extensible as the MSTest command line will allow.

Answer (score 0):

It is calld MSTest. You could just use the exec task to call the executable directly:

(Correct for an old version of NAnt but apparently not any more. [See the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3529768/157672)).

```
<exec>
    <executable>%VS_INSTALL%\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe</executable>
    <baseDirectory>PPRJECT LOCATION</baseDirectory>
    <buildArgs>/testcontainer:TestDLLs /runconfig:localtestrun.Testrunconfig /resultsfile:testResults.trx</buildArgs>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>600</buildTimeoutSeconds>
</exec>
```

I am surprised it does not come with a task built in.

For reference here is a list of [MSTest Command-Line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx).

*NB: these options are for VS2010, it is possible to view the Command-Line options from other VS versions by selecting the correct version on the page*

Comment: Nant seems quite dead now, ms tests were not popular when it was still being developed.

Comment: I disagree, when the last update to nant was 2 days ago (August 17, 2010). I don't think you can really say its 'dead'!

Comment: -1: This syntax no longer works for the latest version of NAnt. Check the accepted answer instead. (This answer does have a link to the MSTest Command-Line Options, I only downvoted so that the correct XML build syntax would show up at the top)